# Prove $m_*( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell ( I_i )$ if $I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset \forall i,j$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Define $m_*(E) = \inf_{E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty J_i} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(J_i)$ where $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty J_i$ is an open cover of $E$ (i.e. an outer measure in $\mathbb{R}$). Let $\ell$ denote the length function.

> If the $I_i$'s are intervals and $I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset$ $\forall i,j$, prove $m_*( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell ( I_i )$.

**Attempt:**

By the definition of outer measure,
$$ m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_i).$$

To prove the other inequality, note that
$$ m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^NI_i ) \leq m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ).$$

At this point, I'm stuck. I would like to assert ** below so that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N\ell(I_i) \underset{**}{\leq} m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_i)$$
and take $N \to \infty$. However, I think I need countable additivity to claim that
$$ m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^NI_i ) \leq m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ) \implies \sum_{i=1}^N\ell(I_i) \leq m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i ).$$
Is the solution as simple as stating that the inequality ** follows because the $I_i$'s are disjoint?

Comment: $inf$ is the infimum taken over all countable unions of open intervals $J_i$ that cover $E$.

Comment: Since $m_\ast$ is monotone, $m_\ast(\bigcup_1^N I_i )\leq m_\ast (\bigcup_1^\infty I_i)$. Thus, it suffices to show $\sum_1^N \ell(I_i) \leq m_\ast (\bigcup_1^N I_i)$ ($\ast$) and then let $N\to \infty$. But the proof of ($\ast$) is **not easy** if you do not know more about the length function on intervals.

Comment: @PhoemueX. Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^N\ell(I_i) =m_*(\bigcup_{i=1}^NI_i )$? I can prove that the outer measure of an interval is its length and, from here, I think I could prove equality rather than $\leq$. Perhaps there's more than one approach.

Comment: Ok, if you already know that the outer measure of an interval is it's length, then the rest of the proof is not too hard anymore. And yes, it suffices to show $\sum_{i=1}^N \ell(I_i) = m_\ast (\bigcup_{i=1}^N I_i)$.